# How to access ColumnChooser's API to toggle the $ui.multiselect components

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to access the jqGrid's columnChooser's multiselect API objects?  I need to call those objects to update the data on ColumnChooser pop-up dialog.

In the snapshot below, is the customized ColumnChooser pop-up dialog.  The HTML combo when selected/changes would then change the $ui.multiselect sections (avaiable & unavailable columns).

In the 2nd snapshot below is the view souce using Firefox's firebug and it doesn't have me the option to toggle the 2 columns.

Is there a way to access ColumnChooser's API instead, to manually toggle the columns on the ColumnChooser but not touch the jqGrid's columns?  How can I accomplish this?

Thanks...

[Snapshot #1]...
[image]
[Snapshot #2]...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of Google surfing, piecing together sample script from lots of example api and coming up with JQuery to find the html path to a clickable anchor link.

**Updated Solution**

The "parmSavedBuildDataFormValueColumnModelSetting" value is the colModel's name you passed on to it, whether it be the values you saved from the database or cookie, or anything for populating the MultiSelect "selected" box-windows.

```
        function JqgridColumnChooserSavedBuildsRecordsMultiselectDialogToggler(parmSavedBuildDataFormValueColumnModelSetting) {
            //Re-order the $.ui.multiselect's columns in 2 boxed-windows (available & unavailable)...
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439072/add-remove-column-handler-on-jqgrid-columnchooser
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526893/jqgrid-columnchooser-unselected-columns-on-the-right-in-alphabetical-order
            var $jqgridColumModelSetting = $('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
            var $jqgridColumNameSetting = $('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colNames');

            //Remove all of the "selected" columns having "-" icon...
           //09/11/2013 - This "selected" columns with hyperlink click event does not work too well as it cause 1/3 of all columns not to be visible, so let' use the "Remove All" hyperlink instead...
            //#$('#colchooser_' + jqgridSpreadsheetId + ' ul.selected a.action').click();
            $('#colchooser_' + jqgridSpreadsheetId + ' div.ui-multiselect div.selected a.remove-all').click();

            //Add back the "available" columns having "+" icon, only the one that match the SavedBuilds data...
            $.each(parmSavedBuildDataFormValueColumnModelSetting.split('|'), function (i1, o1) {  //##parmSavedBuildDataFormValueColumnModelSetting.forEach(function (i, o) {
                $.each($jqgridColumModelSetting, function (i2, o2) {
                    if (o2.name == o1) {
                        $('#colchooser_' + jqgridSpreadsheetId + ' ul.available li[title="' + $jqgridColumNameSetting[i2] + '"] a.action').click();
                        return false;  //This only break the foreach loop [while "return true" resume the loop] (This have nothing to do with function's returned value)...
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```